# Generating quarters based on start date and end date

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to generate a table that contains all quarters based on a start date and an end date. I wrote already a function but unfortunately is not calculating the quarters correctly. For example I have:
- start date: 01.06.2018
- end date: 01.03.2019
My function generates Q2, Q3, Q4 and normally and correctly should generate Q2, Q3, Q4, Q1.

Does anyone have sugestion?

Thank you!

Here is my function:

```
Private Function calculateQuartars(ByVal startDate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date) As Collection
    Dim iDate As Date, i As Integer
    Dim quartal As String
    Dim quartalListe As Collection

    iDate = startDate
    i = 0
    Set quartalListe = New Collection

    If (IsDate(startDate) And IsDate(endDate)) Then
        Do          
            quartal = "Q" & DatePart("q", iDate) & " " & DatePart("yyyy", iDate)
            quartalListe.Add quartal, "Q" & i
            iDate = DateAdd("m", 3, iDate)
            i = i + 1
        Loop While iDate < endDate
    Else
        quartal = ""
        quartalListe.Add quartal, "Q" & i
    End If

    Set calculateQuartars = quartalListe

End Function
```

Comment: Seems like homework that would be helped be using a debugger to see what's going on, seems simple enough :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework and could be solved using a debugger to step through it.

Comment: @Svend I am new to this and before posting this here I already used a debugger. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the below line

`Loop While iDate < endDate`

Your loop exits if the dates are equal

Change it to 
`Loop While iDate <= endDate`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

If (IsDate(startDate) And IsDate(endDate)) Then
            Do
           quartal = "Q" & DatePart("q", iDate) & " " & DatePart("yyyy", iDate)
            iDate = DateAdd("m", 1, iDate)
            If LastQuartal = quartal Then
            Else
            quartal = "Q" & DatePart("q", iDate) & " " & DatePart("yyyy", iDate)
            quartalListe.Add quartal
            LastQuartal = quartal
            End If
        Loop While iDate <= endDate